# vue.js conditional rendering of an attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'd like to learn what is the best way to conditionally render an HTML attribute in Vue.js. For example, add `data-toggle="tooltip"` if there is a tooltip message for current instance.

The code I have now:

```
<span
  :data-toggle="!!col.col_spec.tooltip ? 'tooltip' : ''"
  :title="col.col_spec.tooltip"
>
  {{ col.col_spec.title }}
</span>
```

Though, I don't like the 2nd line much… Even if I use computed property here, I'd prefer not to have `data-toggle` attribute at all, when there is no tooltip to display.

Comment: If you don't want the attribute to exist at all when there is no tooltip, then I would probably not do this in the template, but rather in mounted() or something like that.

Comment: @str not exactly. It's a bit simpler with "required", which is a "boolean attribute". My question concerns "attributes in general".

Comment: @pilat No, it is exactly the same. While `required` indeed is a [boolean attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#boolean-attribute), you can not pass a `false` value to it. "*The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.*" The only way to use it is to either have it in the DOM, or don't.

Comment: Well, it looks that no matter what type of attribute it is, it won't be rendered if it's has 'false' passed to it. Exactly what I needed! 

https://jsbin.com/lamudoqucu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Very so elegant solution:

```
<span
  :data-toggle="!!col.col_spec.tooltip ? 'tooltip' : false"
  :title="col.col_spec.tooltip"
>
  {{ col.col_spec.title }}
</span>
```

Yes, yes, yes, it's just necessary that there is not an *empty string*, but a Boolean **false**

Comment: This answer is the only good and [officially recommended](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes) way to add an attribute conditionally. To remove the attribute, though, it does not necessarily have to be `false`, but could also be `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
<span ref="column">
  {{ col.col_spec.title }}
</span>
```

And in Vue:

```
mounted(){
    if (this.col.col_spec.tooltip){
      this.$refs.column.setAttribute("data-toggle", this.col.col_spec.tooltip);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clean way of doing it

Comment: the attribute wouldn't be at all reactive if `this.col.col_spec.tooltip` changed... and sometimes components don't re-mount eg. if vue-router stays on the same route/page (same components) but goes to a new page (different data/url).  Like navigating from `#/post/1` to `#/post/2`.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but here is my take on it:

HTML:

```
<span
  :data-toggle="tooltip"
  :data-original-title="tooltipTitle"
>
  {{ tooltipTitle }}
</span>
```

Vue:

```
methods: {
    tooltipTitle: function() {
        var title = this.col.col_spec.title;
        if (!!title) return title;
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will remove the "data-original-title" attribute if there is none to display, consequently removing the tooltip altogether. You must use "data-original-title" instead of just "title" because Bootstrap will automatically add it once you initialise the "title" attribute, and changing "title" to false will not remove the "data-original-title".

Answer (score 0):

Here's another working but not so elegant solution:

```
<span v-if="!!col.col_spec.tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" >
    {{ col.col_spec.title }}
</span>
<span v-else >
    {{ col.col_spec.title }}
</span>
```

Comment: Imho anything that goes against the DRY principle should not be shared.